# Magento 2.3.3 Payflow pro integration with PWA

Tags: magento2, payment, pwa, paypal-payflow-pro

I am trying to implement Payflow pro with PWA, I am following https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/graphql/payment-methods/payflow-pro.html document.

But i can not understannd `handlePayflowProResponse` mutation (Step-9), How to implement this and also not clear which API i need to use in PWA.

Let me know if anyone have idea.